# Joda DateTimeFormatter for a string in the form 2020-05-16 01:00+0200

Tags: datetime, parsing, jodatime, datetime-parsing

I am receiving a String with a date in the form `"2020-05-16 01:00+0200"`. I need to parse it into a DateTime object but I cannot find the correct pattern, i.e. `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm????");` How do I include the "+0200" from the String?
Also, is there a way to extract the offset from the DateTime?

Thanks and Brgs.

Comment: Correction: Date String  to parse =  "2020-05-16 01:00+0200" DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm????"); How do I include the "+0200"

Comment: The correction is welcome. Next time please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61868339/edit) your question rather than posting a comment (this time I did it for you).

Answer (score 0):

```
    String dateStringToParse = "2020-05-16 01:00+0200";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ")
            .withOffsetParsed();

    DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(dateStringToParse, formatter);

    System.out.println(dt);
```

Output is:

> 2020-05-16T01:00:00.000+02:00

Standard behaviour of Joda-Time is to parse into your default time zone. The call to `withOffsetParsed()` makes sure that the offset from the string is retained in the parsed `DateTime`.

The documentation of `DateTimeFormat` says about pattern letter `Z`:

> ```
>  Symbol  Meaning                      Presentation  Examples
>  ------  -------                      ------------  -------
>  Z       time zone offset/id          zone          -0800; -08:00; America/Los_Angeles
> ```

And:

> **Zone:** 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, …

To extract the offset:

```
    DateTimeZone z = dt.getZone();
    System.out.println(z);
```

> +02:00

**Link:** [`DateTimeFormat` documentation](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however System.out.println("z = " + z); gives "z = Europe/Berlin" , not "+0200"

Comment: I cannot reproduce that bit, I got the `+02:00` that I reported. Are you sure that you have remembered the `.withOffsetParsed()` bit?

Comment: Can you show me exactly how you do to get `z = Europe/Berlin`, please?